# Azure deploment center does not show all options

Tags: python, azure, deployment, dropbox

So I wish to deploy a website from dropbox to Azure.
To do so, I will be using Azures deploment from dropbox.
But for some reason, I am not given the option to use dropbox.

[All options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkKxf.png)

I am trying to deploy it as a app service running Python 3.7

Comment: Please include the options in your question and not a link to an image.

Comment: I still get Dropbox as a manual deployment option.  Please provide a screenshot of your App Service overview page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe , you are using python 3.7 and Linux environment for your application as i have tried the same and able to reproduce it .

[image]

The deployment options and current limitation on Linux platform are mentioned in this document [Introduction to Azure App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro). These options are only available for Windows Web Apps, not for Linux Web Apps.

Additional reference:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/37041

Hope it helps.